# Импорт текста из RecyclerView в DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, recyclerview.adapter

В `RecyclerView` есть компоненты с различным текстом, мне нужно чтобы по нажатию на компонент у которого есть текст например "Шахматы", открывался `DialogFragment` и в `TextView` которое находиться внутри этого
`DialogFragment` переносился текст "Шахматы" из компонента `RecyclerView`. Я знаю что это легко реализовать с помощью `getStringExtra` но как правильно это написать в `Adpter` не знаю. Помогите правильно написать код.

`Adapter` в котором нужно реализовать эту функцию

```
public class AdapterSkatingRinkSchedule extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterSkatingRinkSchedule.SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder>{
    public ArrayList<ItemSkatingRinkSchedule> mSkatingRinkScheduleList;
    public List<ItemSkatingRinkSchedule> mSearch;
    private AppCompatActivity mActivity;


    public AdapterSkatingRinkSchedule(ArrayList<ItemSkatingRinkSchedule> SkatingRinkScheduleList) {
        mSkatingRinkScheduleList = SkatingRinkScheduleList;
        mSearch = new ArrayList(mSkatingRinkScheduleList);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_srs, parent, false);
        return new SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder(v);

    }

    public static class SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView number_srs, start_time_srs, end_time_srs, cost_1_srs, cost_2_srs;
        public LinearLayout ll_main;

        public SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            number_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number_srs);
            start_time_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.start_time_srs);
            end_time_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.end_time_srs);
            cost_1_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cost_1_srs);
            cost_2_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cost_2_srs);
            ll_main = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_main);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemSkatingRinkSchedule currentItem = mSkatingRinkScheduleList.get(position);
        holder.number_srs.setText(currentItem.get_session_number());
        holder.start_time_srs.setText(currentItem.get_session_start());
        holder.end_time_srs.setText(currentItem.get_session_end());
        holder.cost_1_srs.setText(currentItem.get_weekdays());
        holder.cost_2_srs.setText(currentItem.get_weekends_and_holidays());
        holder.getAdapterPosition();

        holder.ll_main.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            DialogSkatingRinkSchedule dialogSort = new DialogSkatingRinkSchedule();
            dialogSort.show(((AppCompatActivity)v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(), "SortDialog");
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSkatingRinkScheduleList.size();
    }
}
```

Компоновка моего `item` в `RecyclerView`

```
public class ItemSkatingRinkSchedule {
    private final String mText_session_number;
    private final String mText_session_start;
    private final String mText_session_end;
    private final String mText_weekdays;
    private final String mText_weekends_and_holidays;

    private final int mInitialPositon;

    public ItemSkatingRinkSchedule(String text_session_number, String text_session_start, String text_session_end, String text_weekdays, String text_weekends_and_holidays, int initialPosition) {
        mText_session_number = text_session_number;
        mText_session_start = text_session_start;
        mText_session_end = text_session_end;
        mText_weekdays = text_weekdays;
        mText_weekends_and_holidays = text_weekends_and_holidays;
        mInitialPositon = initialPosition;
    }

    public String get_session_number() {
        return mText_session_number;
    }

    public String get_session_start() {
        return mText_session_start;
    }

    public String get_session_end() {
        return mText_session_end;
    }

    public String get_weekdays() {
        return mText_weekdays;
    }

    public String get_weekends_and_holidays() {
        return mText_weekends_and_holidays;
    }

    public int getInitialPositon() {
        return mInitialPositon;
    }

}
```

`xml` файл моего `DialogFragment`

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/Card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/color_8"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/color_1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/color_1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="6dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingVertical="6dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="222dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="fill_vertical"
                    android:text="Номер сеанса"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_8"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/number_srs_2"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_22"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/color_8" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingVertical="6dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="222dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="fill_vertical"
                    android:text="Начало сеанса"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_8"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/start_srs_2"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="10:15"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_22"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/color_8" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingVertical="6dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="222dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="fill_vertical"
                    android:text="Конец сеанса"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_8"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/end_srs_2"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="11:00"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_22"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/color_8" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingVertical="6dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="222dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="fill_vertical"
                    android:text="Будние дни"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_8"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cost_srs_2_1"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="140₽"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_22"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/color_8" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingVertical="6dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="222dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="fill_vertical"
                    android:text="Выходные и праздники"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_8"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cost_srs_2_2"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="150₽"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_22"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я все правильно понял, то попробуйте так:

В коде вашего фрагмента добавьте:

```
 public static DialogSkatingRinkSchedule newInstance(ItemSkatingRinkSchedule itemSkatingRinkSchedule) {
    DialogSkatingRinkSchedule fragment = DialogSkatingRinkSchedule();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("item", itemSkatingRinkSchedule);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}
```

В классе вашего ItemSkatingRinkSchedule добавьте Serializable:

```
class ItemSkatingRinkSchedule implements Serializable
```

При нажатии на элемент recyclerView :

```
holder.ll_main.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        DialogSkatingRinkSchedule dialogSort = DialogSkatingRinkSchedule.newInstance(currentItem);
        dialogSort.show(((AppCompatActivity)v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(), "SortDialog");
    });
```

Ну и потом в методе onCreateView вашего фрагмента DialogSkatingRinkSchedule:

```
ItemSkatingRinkSchedule item = getArguments.getSerializable("item");
```

Ну и берите от этого объекта что хотите и вставляйте куда вам угодно.